# LocalDate.format causes OutofBount Exception in Observer

Tags: kotlin, material-design, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm making an app in android using Kotlin, Material Design Components and the new architecture components.
I have an activity that starts a DialogFragment onCreate

The fragment has 6 Views that, via an observer, observe a different LiveDate for each and every one.

While checking all the this setup work I noticed that after 7 view switching I get

```
2020-05-12 20:43:19.346 4778-4778/package E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event. 
2020-05-12 20:43:19.346 4778-4778/package E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 
2020-05-12 20:43:19.357 4778-4778/package E/MessageQueue-JNI:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
at android.text.Layout$HorizontalMeasurementProvider.get(Layout.java:1589)
...
```

I cheked the following things:

- did all the setup on only one view -> still crashes
- did all the setup on only one view but without using the "createDateFieldObserver" method -> still carshes
- not calling the observer -> no crash
- calling the observer but without the LocalDate.format -> no crash

I concluded the probleme is in the format function but I do not understand why.
The error is not pointing in that direction.
Any ideas?

Activity code

```
class UITestingActivity: FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_greenhouse)
        val dialog = LabTimesDialogFragment()
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "LabTimes")
    }
}
```

Fragment Code

```
class TimesDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    companion object Companion {
        private val TAG: String = "TimesDialog"
    }
    private val datesViewModel: TimesViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var datesViews: Map<LiveData<LocalDate>, TextInputEditText>


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) : Dialog {
        val viewsArray: Array<TextInputEditText>
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater

            val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filter_times, null)

            builder.setView(rootView)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.feed) { dialog, id -> closeDialog() }
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { dialog, id -> getDialog()?.cancel() }

            val dialog: AlertDialog =  builder.create()

            val fromSampling: TextInputEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.from_sampling) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing date view in LabTimesFilterDialog")
            val toSampling: TextInputEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.to_sampling) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing date view in LabTimesFilterDialog")
            val fromSending: TextInputEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.from_sending) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing date view in LabTimesFilterDialog")
            val toSending: TextInputEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.to_sending) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing date view in LabTimesFilterDialog")
            val fromReceiving: TextInputEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.from_receiving) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing date view in LabTimesFilterDialog")
            val toReceiving: TextInputEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.to_receiving) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Missing date view in LabTimesFilterDialog")
            datesViews = mapOf(datesViewModel.fromSampling to fromSampling,
                    datesViewModel.toSampling to toSampling,
                    datesViewModel.fromSending to fromSending,
                    datesViewModel.toSending to toSending,
                    datesViewModel.fromReceiving to fromReceiving,
                    datesViewModel.toReceiving to toReceiving
            )
            for ((liveData, textView) in datesViews) {
                liveData.observe(this, createDateFieldObserver(textView))
                textView.setOnClickListener { v ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "hello"+v.id)
                }
            }

            return dialog
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }

    private fun closeDialog() {
        // save dates to ViewModel
        // closeDialog
        TODO()
    }

    private fun createDateFieldObserver(tw: TextInputEditText): Observer<LocalDate> {
        return Observer { date ->
            Log.d(TAG, "obs"+tw.id)
            tw.setText(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE))
            //tw.setText("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class TimesViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val fromSampling: MutableLiveData<LocalDate> = MutableLiveData(LocalDate.now())
    val toSampling: MutableLiveData<LocalDate> = MutableLiveData(LocalDate.now())
    val fromSending: MutableLiveData<LocalDate> = MutableLiveData(LocalDate.now())
    val toSending: MutableLiveData<LocalDate> = MutableLiveData(LocalDate.now())
    val fromReceiving: MutableLiveData<LocalDate> = MutableLiveData(LocalDate.now())
    val toReceiving: MutableLiveData<LocalDate> = MutableLiveData(LocalDate.now())
}
```

it has been a while since I programmed for android. Everything I'm using here is new to me so if you spot an anti-pattern in this little code I would be glad to know.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because of the layout.
There was no enough room in the view to display the whole date.
I don't understand why it causes indexoutofbound but the solution is to simply make the view "wrap_content" or bigger